# Higher-order finite difference -- Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

Suppose I want to use the 4-th order accurate [central finite-difference scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient#Central_finite_difference) for a boundary value problem with the second derivative on regularly spaced nodes in $[0, 1]$, with (homogeneous) Dirichlet boundary conditions. Say I have 5 interior nodes, $\mathbf{u}$. My differential operator matrix becomes:

$$
\mathbf{L} \mathbf{u}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c & b & a &   &   \\
b & c & b & a &   \\
a & b & c & b & a \\
  & a & b & c & b \\
  &  & a & b & c \\
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u},
$$

which arises by setting
$$u(0) = u(1) = 0 \qquad (2)$$

and
$$u(0-dx) = u(1+dx) = 0. \qquad (3)$$

Note that the latter (ghost point) conditions are necessary because of the higher-order scheme.
However, I'm not sure if this use of ghost points is quite appropriate because, in effect, I'm fixing $u$ over intervals, rather than at points. Indeed, if I compute the eigenvalue decomposition of this matrix, the eigenvectors differ slightly, but significantly, from their theoretical counterparts (which they do not if use the simpler 2nd order scheme).

Of course, I could instead reduce the accuracy of the finite-difference scheme near the boundaries, Or I could use a non-central scheme near the boundaries. However, both of those solutions would ruin the symmetry of $\mathbf{L}$, which I find undesirable (for example for efficient inversion).

So what is the best way to go about this? Is my use of ghost points really appropriate?

#### Edit1:

I believe that instead of using (3) to specify the ghost points, I should impose the Dirichlet conditions on the ***average*** around the boundaries:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{u(-dx) + u(+dx)}{2} = 0, \qquad (4)
\\
\text{i.e.} \quad u_{-1} = - u_{1} \qquad (5)
\end{align*}
$$
And in the case of even higher-order central differences, $u_{-n} = - u_{n}$, for $n$ between 1 and the number of ghost points. I've checked, and this produces an operator matrix that is symmetric, and whose eigenvectors equal the theoretical ones. So I guess my question becomes: does anybody have a name and theoretical reference for this approach?

Comment: With pure Dirichlet, this does not seem right. One thing you might try is writing down Robin conditions with ghost points (with an equal order discretization of the derivative at the boundary to what you use in the bulk) and sending the conductivity to infinity, i.e. $u_x=Ku$ where $K \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I don't quite understand, though, why should I change my boundary conditions?

Comment: This is a way to get a ghost point implementation of the Dirichlet condition that is consistent with the weak formulation of the BVP.

Comment: Let me come back later and clean up my explanation / give a demonstration of what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I admit I'm still not seeing it, and looking around for references.

Comment: The main concept here is from physics: a Dirichlet condition in the heat equation arises when you put the system in perfect thermal contact with a reservoir at a given temperature, so the high conductivity limit of the Robin condition converges to the Dirichlet condition. At the PDE level you can show this convergence rigorously. That said I counted variables wrong, you would need two conditions per endpoint for your scheme, which you don't actually have.

Comment: @Ian Hello, could you please explain how to put the two conditions per endpoint in the matrix ? or link to an example ? For a second order PDE with one condition per boundary, it seemed easy but I don't how to proceed with 4 BC ?